# Data migration from liferay portal to websphere portal

Tags: migration, liferay, portlet, websphere-portal, ibm-connections

i need to migrate the content of the list below from liferay Portal to WebSphere Portal. and we will use IBM Connection for the portlets.

a. Calendar.

b. Discussion Boards/Blogs/Forums

can anyone give me an API that can be use for migrating the data?
I have an options here but i dont see results in the web.

1. liferayAPI that will export data/content (LAR? ) and import to websphere portal
2. export data/content csv file and create a program that will create new blogs,forums etc to Websphere portal.

thank you,

-Jhei

Comment: you should not need to migrate any of the Connections data, you should only need to export/migrate the configurationd ata

Comment: can you explain it further? im new to Connections. thanks.

Comment: if you are changing the display from liferay to websphere portal, you should need to migrate data, you would need to migrate the display/configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have small amount of data set then, it would be good to create a migration app with uses RESTfull WEb-services/Direct DB interaction if you have, which will fetch data from Liferay and push data to Webspear.

Comment: thank you for your response.

but i dont see a tutorial for pushing data to websphere. please help me, how will do this. im searching for 2weeks but there's no result :<

Comment: For "WebSphere" part, I'm sorry, I really can't help you (I didn't work on it for real time scenarios) and It's again IBM. But I'm sure you can find some reference from their documentation.

I found a this link [link](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/lcwiki.nsf/dx/Using_IBM_Connections_more_as_a_platform_than_an_application#What+can+Connections+REST+APIs+bring+to+us%3F). I don't know if it would be usefull or not, just a arrow in the dark.

With Liferay, it already exposes REST services. So that part won't be difficult to figure out.

Comment: Thanks! i researched if there's already REST services that will export all data of Blogs/ forums but i dont see result. do i need to create REST service for this. im hoping that there's API that i can use retrieving the data/content of blogs/forums .

Thank you. i really appreciate your help.

Comment: For Liferay, you already have it. Start your Liferay server --> hit "http://server-name:port/api/jsonws". You can see whole exposed api methods. With help of this, you can retrieve blogs/forums from Liferay, now you have to manage the "WebSphere" side.

Comment: "Down Vote"... May I know the reason for it??